# jQuery plugin not working - it's appended

Tags: jquery, append, jquery-chosen

Im appending (*or duplicating in other words*) a `<form>` which includes dropdown - all my dropdowns are using [Chosen jQuery plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

**PROBLEM:** appended form's dropdown is not working!

How to make it work when it's appended?

Obviously the problem is that jQuery script is not attached to new/appended dropdown becuause HTML is 100% same but how to do this?

---

```
<form class="my-form">
   <div class="new-item row">
    <select name="transport-type[]">
        <option value=""><?php _e('Type', 'tt'); ?></option>
        <option value="coach"><?php _e('Coach', 'tt'); ?></option>
        <option value="diesel-train"><?php _e('Diesel Train', 'tt'); ?></option>
        <option value="electric-train"><?php _e('Electric Train', 'tt'); ?></option>
        <option value="trolley"><?php _e('Trolley', 'tt'); ?></option>
        <option value="tram"><?php _e('Tram', 'tt'); ?></option>
        <option value="city-bus"><?php _e('City Bus', 'tt'); ?></option>
        <option value="shuttle"><?php _e('Shuttle', 'tt'); ?></option>
    </select> 
  </div>
</form>

<div class="clearfix">
    <a class="add-new btn"><?php _e( 'Add New','tt' ); ?></a>
</div>  



<?php

//All JS is on different file & is included before HTML

//Fires up / "attaches" Chosen.js to select
jQuery('select').chosen({
    disable_search: false,
    disable_search_threshold: 10,
    width: '100%'
});

//Add new
jQuery(document).on('click', '.add-new', function() {
     newGroup = jQuery('.new-item').html();
     jQuery('.my-form').append('<div class="new-item row">'+newGroup+'</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grab the `.new-item`'s HTML before it is transformed by chosen.

Try this:

```
//Fires up / "attaches" Chosen.js to select
var newGroup = jQuery('.new-item:first').html();
jQuery('select').chosen({
    disable_search: false,
    disable_search_threshold: 10,
    width: '100%'
});

//Add new
var group_id = 0;
jQuery(document).on('click', '.add-new', function() {
     group_id++;
     jQuery('.my-form').append('<div class="new-item row" id="group_' + group_id + '" >'+newGroup+'</div>');
     jQuery('#group_' + group_id + ' select').chosen({
         disable_search: false,
         disable_search_threshold: 10,
         width: '100%'
     });
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/qfvhyg4y/

Comment: I can't call it multiple times because it "makes" 2 dropdowns - one works, one doesn't. Could you give me an example based on my code what you think when you're talking about generated ID?

Comment: I'll need to see your code that generates `newGroup` (formally known as `transportGroup`)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try your suggestion as soon as I can. `newGroup = jQuery('.new-item').html();` is really that simple - nothing else to add.

Answer (score 0):

move your script to end of your html code or put your script in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('select').chosen({
               disable_search: false,
               disable_search_threshold: 10,
               width: '100%'
         });
});
```

Comment: Im afraid it doesn't change anything - jQuery script is still not attached to appended element.

Comment: use an id for your select and try somthing like this $('#select-id') for selecting that element with jquery selector